Closing up spacing in Knight Lab's Timeline JS
Using Timeline JS, I can't find the CSS needed to close up the vertical space between the items and the top of div & timeline. I've made some CSS edits already, but can't see what  to target to close up this space. See attached.
Stack Exchange insists I write more here, though I've already asked my question.


What code do you see when using your browser devtools inspect facility, ie exactly what CSS is being applied? And please show what you have tried.

I've poked around with devtools, and review the linked CSS, but cannot ID the element that is applying the spacing.

Height is set when calling the div:
<div id='timeline-embed' style="width: 100%; height: 450px"></div>

Then slides' space is calculated as 450px - 165px = 335px. This is the available space for slides, and experimenting with the height setting allows you to find the optimum setting to close up the extra space.
